# Use Singleton Throughout All Node.js Modules

Tags: node.js

I want to somehow create a global singleton module.  I'm using it as the context module where I can reference it in any of my modules.

I'll use it to get to my gateway (repository) module for use in other modules like my business object modules etc.  So for example let's say I have:

**myBusinessModule.js**

```
module.exports = {
      find: function(id){
         var user = context.userGateway.find(id);
      }
};
```

So I want to be able to use the `context` singleton to get at other modules in my node app.

Just like the same thing here, this is Java but same concept I want to do something like this in Node.JS: [CleanCodeCaseStudy](https://github.com/cleancoders/CleanCodeCaseStudy/tree/master/src/cleancoderscom)

Comment: What is the actual question here? How to create a singleton in nodejs? Modules are already singletons in node. You get the same object back from `require()` even from multiple locations.

Comment: yea create a singleton and be able to share it across all node modules

Comment: ok so it's literally just create a require with maybe a json object with properties that point to other requires?

Comment: @WeDoTDD In Node.js modules are loaded in memory only once and then they will be cached. Subsequent `require` calls load the module object from the cache.

Comment: ok thanks.  I guess I still don't understand how I can sorta create a global config then that provides requires to some of my top level modules.  Like I wanna do context.someOtherModule where someOtherModule is set to another require in context

Comment: what I'm trying to do is not have to repeat the same require multiple times across many modules.  I can reduce the requires at the top by shoving most of them into a main context json object or something, you know what I mean?  Instead of having teh same set of requires at the top of every module, I wanna just centralize and reference them from a central json object or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, to me it looks like you want something like this. Please correct me if i wrongly understood your requirement.

**Access with require()**

context.js

```
var context = {};
context.userGateway = require('../path/to/userGateway/module');

module.exports.context = context;
=====================================================================================

//usage in reference file
var context = require('/path/to/context/file');
module.exports = {
      find: function(id){
         var user = context.userGateway.find(id);
      }
};
```

**Access without require()**

```
var context = {};
context.userGateway = require('../path/to/userGateway/module');

GLOBAL.context = context; // makes your context object accessible globally, just like, console, require, module etc.

=====================================================================================

//usage in reference file
module.exports = {
      find: function(id){
         var user = context.userGateway.find(id); 
      }
};
```